# RabbitMQ Shovel - unable to connect on different machines using dockers

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-shovel

I have following RabbitMQ config on machine A:

```
[
  {rabbit,
    [
      {default_user, <<"user">>},
      {default_pass, <<"pass">>}
    ]
  },

{rabbitmq_shovel,
 [{shovels, [{shovel_test,
              [{sources, [{brokers, ["amqp://"]}]},
               {destinations, [{broker, "amqp://user:password@ip_of_machine_B:5672"}]},
               {queue, <<"queue_test">>},
               {prefetch_count, 1},
               {ack_mode, on_confirm},
               {publish_properties, [ {delivery_mode, 2} ]},
               {reconnect_delay, 5}
              ]}
            ]}
 ]}
].
```

RabbitMQ with Shovel plugin on machine A is in docker network and RabbitMQ  on machine B is in another docker network. On machine B port 5672 is open. After putting some messages to first RabbitMQ it doesn't send it to second one.

Any ideas? Is it problem with Rabbits or with machines?

Comment: Are both in same subnet? Are you using `docker-compose` to start these machines?

Comment: Aslo, can you ping A from B and vice versa?

Comment: Yes, I use docker-compose to start these machines. Forgot to add, They are on the same physical machine, but 2 different virtual machines.

Comment: Not machines but RabbitMQs containers ofc*. Ping works.

Comment: Perhaps then 5672 is not exposed? Are these default RMQ dokcer images?

Comment: Port 5672 is exposed on machine B's RabbitMQ (destination one). Is everything OK with config posted above?

Comment: ever get any resolution to this?